# How to get correct innerWidth of the screen after rotate?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, mobile, react-pdf

I try to get the innerWidth of the screen and I manage to do this but when I go to the page on mobile view I get firstly 375 after going to the landscape I get 667 and when returning back to portrait I get 618. Why is it different when I return from landscape than when I navigate form another page?
What I did:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and this is how I get the width

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const useWindowWidth = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const handleResize = () => {setWidth(window.innerWidth);}
  
      window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  
      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
      };
    }, []);
  
    return (    <WrappedComponent {...props} width={width} />
    )
  }

export default useWindowWidth;
```

I need width in js because I have to set the width of react-pdf from npm and it should be set in the props of the component.

```
       let windowWidth = width * 0.9;
   return (
       <Document
        file={url}
        onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        className={classes.pdfFileContainer}
      >
        <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} width={windowWidth} />
      </Document>
);
```

Comment: Instead of resize try listening [to orientationchange event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientationchange_event)

Comment: The same behavior.

Comment: Why do you even set the width via JS like this? Why not use CSS for this?

Comment: I need to set width in js, added it in the question.